# how to redirect my domain to my magento's index.php?

Tags: magento, bitnami

I have a godaddy domain www.example.com. And i have forwarded it to my aws(amazon web services) elastic IP. But my domain is getting forwarded to bitnami's congratulation page instead of my magento application. I want to redirect my domain to magento's application instead of bitnami's congratulations page. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find that the default Bitnami Apache configuration is forcefully rewriting all requests to the welcome page. Bitnami AMI's are designed in a way that you need to set up your application using their tools/web interface, which are then exposed at a specific URL context (i.e. http://domain.com/myapp/)

If you want to get around this, you can try modifying the files in the Apache config directory (/etc/httpd/conf.d/*), or use an AMI that isn't preconfigured with that toolset such as Amazon Linux or Ubuntu.

Comment: i have made changes in config file(i.e. /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf). i have changed ServerRoot, DocumentRoot and Directory from "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs" to "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs". But now the problem is that my domain is getting forwarded to magento's index.php bt it's not getting loaded into the browser. Browser is blank. Please tell me is there anything more to do or am i wrong anywhere??

Comment: or should i wait for some time? will take time to reflect the changes?